# Enable Entity Framework Auto Migration for sub project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a solution with two project. One is entities class project, another is ASP.net mvc 4 project.

```
-solution
  -project.domain
  -project.web
```

All the entity models are in the domain project, and the web project is using all the entities from the model.

Which project should I enable Entity Framework Auto Migration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable migrations for domain project.

In Package Manager Console window, you can select project from drop down list.
Select your domain project then type "enable-migrations" and hit enter

Answer (score 1):

In your Package Manager console select the project with the classes/objects (i.e. the domain project)

And the command for automatic migrations is

```
enable-migrations
```

And it will generate a Migrations folder with a Configuration.cs file.
Change the constructor to allow automatic migrations

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
}
```

At any point of time if you want to update the database you can use (in Nuget)

```
update-database
```